# Git checkout does not work

Tags: git

I am sorry for the sudden request but I need help. 
I am managing a project with git. Now, of course the files generated by the compiler are left out from staging. However I commited a mistake and one file that is generated by the making process was being tracked and I ignored that.

Everything was proceeding well, but then I wanted to check a previous commit so I did

`git checkout previous_commit`

So I had the previous version of it. *Then I built the project* and obviously that modified that file I am talking about. (so this file is "uncommited")

I want to go back to the last commit I was working on so I did

`git checkout last_commit`

but now git is refusing to comply:

> error your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>         the_file_with_problem.dep
>   Please commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches 
>   Aborting

So as you can see, git has detected that by me building the project I have modified this file so it doesn't want me to go back

### How do I correct this error, go back to the last commit and of course prevent this from happening again by unstaging this problematic file??

edit:

I think I was not very clear, I am sorry. I will try to summarize here.

Let's say that I have a software project. I build it, and then commit it
The name of this commit is previous_commit.

Then I make even more changes to it, and commit it. The name of this commit is last_commit.

So we have   previous_commit--> last_commit

However I can not build this last version of the project, got some linking errors so I say. hummmm wonder what is wrong, let's see how my previous version worked.

So I go back to the previous commit *and build it*.

All I want to do is go back to the previous commit, check some things and go back to my last commit. Very simple.

The problem is that when I built the previous commit, it modified some file, so git is considering that I modified some file and doesn't want to go back "because I will lose the changes"

I just want to go back to where I was originally. that is it

(and of course unstage that problematic file that shouldn't have been staged in the first place)

Comment: If you don't care aboujt your local changes just do `git reset --hard HEAD` and then checkout.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Do you want to rewrite the commit where you accidentally committed the make file?  Do you want to revert the addition of that file?

Comment: @KansaiRobot why do you need to go back to the old commit, if you corrected the file you can commit it

Comment: I am sorry, may be I was not clear. I will edit the question with more info

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have 3 options,

1. If you do not want the changes to be committed as a new commit (
   commit just after the latest commit) but need to keep the changes
   temporarily saved in somewhere for further development and commit
   later, you can `stash` the changes and switch to the other commit. 
   Then later you can get the `stash` content back when you
   need, check these links [link1](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) [link2](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history)
2. or else you can amend the new changes to the latest commit without
   creating a new commit, [Read this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-commit--amend)
3. or what you need is just to see what other changes that you made in
   the latest commit you can checkout to a temp branch using

   git checkout -b temp-branch-name

   and when done you can delete the branch

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers. I found a way to do what I wanted

`git checkout -- <problem file>`

then 
`git checkout last_commit`

Now I have to find a way to unstage this problematic file